# How do I resolve 'int' object not callable error

Tags: python

```
class MyMath(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    @property
    def get_value(self):
        print("Getting Value")
        return self.value

    @get_value.setter
    def set_value(self, value):
        print("Setting value")
        self.value = value

    def is_gcd(self,other):
        if self.get_value == 0:
            return other.get_value()
        if other.get_value() == 0:
            return self.value
        if self.value == other.get_value():
            return self.value
        while self.value > other.get_value():
            print(self.value-other.value)
            break
        while self.value < other.get_value():
            print(other.get_value()-self.value)
            break


a = MyMath(0)
b = MyMath(100)
print(a.is_gcd(b))
```

Before I added the @property class, the solution of finding the GCD was perfectly fine, after adding the @property method, I keep getting errors 'int' object not callable. How can I solve the problem

Comment: The whole point of `@property` is to make a function act like a variable. So you don't put `()` after it.

Comment: What's the point of these properties, anyway? `self.value` and `self.get_value` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks very Much, It worked. It was an assignment. That's why I had to use the @property method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyMath(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @property
    def get_value(self):
        print("Getting Value")
        return self.value

    @get_value.setter
    def set_value(self, value):
        print("Setting value")
        self.value = value

    def is_gcd(self, other):
        if self.get_value == 0:
            return other.get_value
        if other.get_value() == 0:
            return self.value
        if self.value == other.get_value:
            return self.value
        while self.value > other.get_value:
            print(self.value - other.value)
            break
        while self.value < other.get_value:
            print(other.get_value - self.value)
            break


a = MyMath(0)
b = MyMath(100)
print(a.is_gcd(b))
```

There should be no parentheses after `get_value` call

Comment: accept (and possibly upvote) the answer then

Comment: How do I accept the answer? I can't see any accept option